# How to find area covered by a car windshield wiper when it swaps a certain angle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> A buggy is set to cross over a snowy terrain. The driver seat has a
> rectangular window featured in the diagram from below. When the driver
> activates the mechanism for cleaning the window from the snow, the
> wiper spins $120^{\circ}$ using the point $M$ as a pivot. Assuming the
> rotation is clockwise. Find the area covered by the windshield wiper
> in the buggy. Assume the wiper has a T shape and the rectangular
> window is $ABCD$ where $BC=2AB=2AE=2AM=1\,m$. Also assume AE is
> perpendicular to $MN$ and $N$ is midpoint between $AE$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}\right)\,m^{2}\\
2.&\left(\frac{\pi}{16}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}\right)\,m^{2}\\
3.&\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}\right)\,m^{2}\\
4.&\left(\frac{\pi}{16}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}\right)\,m^{2}\\
\end{array}$

So far the only thing which I could come up with was the diagram from below:

[image: Sketch of the solution]

However I don't know how to find such area. I remember how to calculate the area of a half circle sector by means of the equation:

$A=\frac{\alpha}{360}\pi r^2$

Assuming $\alpha$ is an angle given in sexagesimal units. But in this case the figure doesn't help much. How exactly should I find that weird surface.

Can someone help me with a method relying euclidean geometry or something along precalculus?. I think integrals can be used but I am not looking for such sort of answer.

**Please include a drawing in the answer** because for me it is not easy to spot how to find such problematic area. Does it require some sort of construction?.

Comment: Another [ridiculous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3889448/1508)! Where do you get them from? Can you imagine a worse design for a windscreen wiper?

Comment: @TonyK I think whoever proposed this question was only trying to adapt a geometrical situation to a real scenario. Regarding designs of windscreen wiper. Regarding designs I think it is only a hypothetical scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The area we want to find out is the one surrounded by red in the figure above. This is the worst windshield wiper ever.

To verify this, we know that since $\overline{AE}\perp\overline{MN}$, the inner circle — with center $M$ and radius $\overline{MN}$ — will never be reached. Same with the two blue areas at the left and right bottom corner.

I assume that it was the inaccurate figure you have that misled you. Anyway, here's my solution. The length and area unit below are  $m$ and $m^2$, respectively.

Let's find out the length of $\overline{MN}$ first by noting that $\triangle ANM$ is a right triangle with $\angle AMN=30^{\circ}$. Therefore $$\overline{AM}=0.5\Longrightarrow \overline{MN}=\frac{\sqrt3}4$$

Now let's compute the red area. Let it be $S$.

$$\begin{align}S&=\frac{1}2\cdot (0.5)^2\pi-\frac{120}{360}\cdot \left(\frac{\sqrt3}4\right)^2\pi-2\triangle ANM\\
&=\frac{\pi}8-\frac{\pi}{16}-2\cdot \frac{1}2\cdot \frac{1}4\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}4\\&=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{16}-\frac{\sqrt3}{16}}
\end{align}$$

which is the final answer.

Comment: Howdy!. I have checked with the answers sheet for this particular question and they say the answer is the option $4$, which from looking at your method of solution, doesn't give much sense. (Referring to the answer my book says). Regarding the figure, sorry it was my best effort. **I figured out** that it made sense that the *area* was generated by the wiper when this is below the segment $AE$ and **not** what is upper that segment, which you have colorized with red. But **I believe your interpretation is correct**.

Comment: *Again* when you reassured that the inner center will never be reached was exactly the nail in the head which made me understand your logic in this problem. Which if you think about it, doesn't seem very *real* if you see a window when traveling inside a car, **typically** the wiper cleans an area which is wide enough and although doesn't touches the inner center it does generate a sector similar in shape to which I had drawn. Out of curiosity **if we intend to match the answer** what sort of change would be needed to perform in this question?. **Maybe the given lenghts?**.

Comment: I've also have been trying to change them but it doesn't seem to be possible in the sense that they have been chosen in such a way that with those you can find the tilt angle of the windshield wiper with respect of the horizontal. Btw I figured out that if you use an approach of using dots instead of straight lines will ease a better identification of the area generated by the swept of the figure. I don't use geogebra much but if it could allow fill in regions which would help better in identifying the area. As distinguishing between blue and red **thin** lines is a bit difficult.

Comment: Oh wait I think I got it. I had all the lengths twice those given in the question! No wonder my answer is 4 times the correct answer!

Comment: I edited my answer. Yes option $4$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Btw, there’s no option to fill color in geogebra. I am not making a excuse. I have tried drawing a lot of dense colored lines to get the similar outcome but it takes too much time. I should have continued what I was doing. I am sorry.

Comment: "This is the worst windshield wiper ever." Indeed!

Comment: @Student1058 You sir are No.1. Hats off. After some attempts I also **noticed the error** in the computation of the area. Regarding geogebra that's fine. Btw I suggest you may give a try to inkscape because not only is free but also allows better manipulation of the images. However *geogebra* is intended for math use which inkscape is more vector art oriented. Needless to say your help is **very much appreciated**.

Comment: @Student1058 Hi. By the way. I added a revisited version of the windscreen wiper problem which references your effort in a new answer seen below. *You may feel free to leave any comments.* I took into consideration your observations. I added my findinds and explained the reason of the initial confusion. Again, xie xie :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Student1058's  answer I'm posting a revisited version of my attempt solved properly with some annotations which may help somebody in a similar situation.

Typically if you are inside a car and look at the area swept by a windshield wiper you'll notice it generates an area of a semicircle. This happens because the **swept** is generated by the rotation of the arm which is covered by a **cleaning foam** or a **rubber blade** which doesn't cover all the arm of the wiper. This is better understood in the graphic from below:

[image: Sketch of the solution showcasing the wiper]

However in this sort of problem it seems a bit challenging and at the same part confusing if you rush to believe that the segment perpendicular forming the $T$ (meaning $MN \perp AE$) also acts as a **normal wiper**. **But this is not meant as the correct interpretation of the problem** as it indicates, **only the area which is swept by the arm** $AE$. (See images below)

This jumps into the question, **how do you find such area?**. The best method is to build a tangential circle enclosing the inner part of the wiper. In geometrical terms, this is translated as **drawing a circle tangential** to point $N$.

The next thing we want to do is to make another circle but this time, one which touches the points $A$ and $E$ (**yes similar to the [tv channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%26E_(TV_network))**).

In this case. This happens because the angle on $\angle NAM = 30^{\circ}$.

Because:

Since $AM=\frac{1}{2}\,m$ and $N$ is midpoint of $AM$ then $AN=NE=\frac{1}{4}\,m$

Since $\triangle ANM$ is a right triangle whose sides are:

$NA=\frac{1}{4}$

$\textrm{hypotenuse}=\frac{1}{2}$

Then this proportion lead us to indicate it is a $30-60-90$ Pythagorean triangle, more properly is a **[special right triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_right_triangle)**.

Where the sides are in a proportion of:

$\textrm{hypotenuse}= 2k$

$\textrm{side opposing 30 degrees}= k$

$\textrm{side opposing 60 degrees}= k\sqrt 3$

To obtain $NM=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$ and since $\triangle ANM \cong$ to $\triangle ENM$ this led us to indicate $\angle\,ENM= 30^{\circ}$ and $NM=\textrm{is bisector and median hence a mediatrix}$.

Therefore the $\angle AEM = \angle EMA = 60^{\circ}$ thus making our $\triangle\,AEM$ isosceles into an **equilateral triangle**. Thus perfectly fitting **one-third** of the semicircle. Referring to the semicircle between points $AD$.

*Had this angle not occured then it would follow the same strategy*, you can always make two circles, both tangential to the inner part from where is about to be rotated and the other one touching both ends of the segment, the only difference will lie on the slope of the segment.

Since it is not easy to spot how the arm generates the area. I made succesive stops along the way as the wiper moves touching both cirles. The image from below showcases this motion.

[image: Sketch of the rotation and area swept]

As now it is proved that we must only focus in the areas covered first by the arc between $AN$ and the ring between $NN$ and finally from the arc between $NE$.

From a visual inspection we can notice that since arc $AN$ equals to the arc $NE$ their swept areas will be the same.

Thus we proceed to calculate such areas:

The easiest part is the ring:

This comes from:

$A=\frac{r^2\theta}{2}$

where $\theta=\textrm{given in radian units}$

therefore: $As \frac{120^{\circ}}{180}\pi=\frac{2\pi}{3}$

$A_{NN}=\frac{(r_1^2-r_2^2)\frac{2\pi}{3}}{2}=\frac{(\frac{1}{2}^2-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}^2)\frac{2\pi}{3}}{2}$

$A_{NN}=\frac{\pi}{48}$

Now we will focus in the other two arcs:

This can be obtained by subtracting our right triangle from the circle sector on $NAM$

Hence:

$A_{AN}=\left[\frac{r_{AM}^2\theta_{\angle\,NMA}}{2}\right]-A_{\triangle\,NAM}$

since: $\theta_{\angle\,NMA}=\frac{30\pi}{180}=\frac{\pi}{6}$

This means:

$A_{AN}=\left[\frac{\frac{1}{2}^2}{2}\cdot\frac{\pi}{6}\right]-\frac{\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}}{2}$

$A_{AN}=\frac{\pi}{48}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{32}$

Since $A_{AE}=A_{AN}$

Notice here we're referring as $AN$ and $NE$ as the arcs.

The total area would be:

$A_{\textrm{swept area}}=A_{NN}+2A_{AN}=\frac{\pi}{48}+2\left(\frac{\pi}{48}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{32}\right)$

Finally becoming into:

$A_{\textrm{swept area}}=\frac{\pi}{16}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}\,m$

Which corresponds to the fourth option.

This explanation is the most complete I could write. Which hope may help in any similar cases.